# Powershell - associate/import a certificate with RD Gateway

Tags: windows, powershell, ssl

I'm automating the setup of an RD gateway server but try as i might i cant see how select and associate an ssl certificate from the local store with. In the UI in TS gateway manager i just use  "select an existing certificate from the RD gateway" and select the "Import Certificate" button and select my cert.
I am installing RD gateway without the RD session host. 
Ideally id like to do it in Powershell but any command line tool would suffice.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your certificate already exists in the local store, the PowerShell you need is this:

```
$RDSCertPath = 'RDS:\GatewayServer\SSLCertificate\Thumbprint'
$Store = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store('My','LocalMachine')
$Store.Open('ReadOnly')
$Thumbprint = $Store.Certificates | where {$_.Subject -Eq $RDGCertificateSubject}
Set-Item -Path $RDSCertPath -Value $Thumbprint.Thumbprint
```

The Subject for your certificate (`$RDGCertificateSubject`) will most-likely be the computer name prepended with `'CN='` - if you're unsure, you can either open it via the Certificates MMC snap-in and view the **Issuer** property in the **Details** tab, or alternatively run up until the first three lines then run `$Store.Certificates` to see the Subject for all the certificates you've currently got in the Personal store.